# IIf function returning sum of sum in report builder

Tags: sql, sum, reportbuilder, iif

```
=IIf(Fields!HOLDER_UNIT.Value = 'BOX', Sum(Fields!f1.Value) + Sum(Fields!f3.Value),0)
```

Is it possible to return a sum of sum as a value in Iff function?
I need to filter on value 'BOX' and if it is BOX, then return a sum of 2 other sums calculated in the query, otherwise, return 0.

Can this work? If yes, how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can just `Sum(Fields!f1.Value + Fields!f3.Value)`. And, by the way, before asking, you could actually try it yourself

Comment: Thank you, this works, but not when I use it in Iff like below: =IIf(Fields!HOLDER_UNIT.Value ='BOX', Sum(Fields!f1.Value + Fields!f3.Value), 0) and I tried various combinations, but doesn't work any combination I have tried.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? `iif()` is non-standard

Answer (score 0):

I am using potashin's tip from the comments.

You are already really close, here is what you want:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!HOLDER_UNIT.Value ='BOX', Sum(Fields!f1.Value + Fields!f3.Value), 0))
```